# Getting Information about which uid is playing Audio [Android]

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I want to add a feature which requires the information about which all uid(or applications) are currently playing audio.

I know about AudioManager but it doesn't give info about which apps are playing audio, only thing it tells is whether audio is being played or not.

Comment: please help, If you know the answer..